# Cannot trim object properties using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, trim

I have not been able to find a way to trim (get rid of the white space at the beginning and end of each string) the properties of the array of objects in my code. Following the advice in other threads on here did not work.
I have an array of objects named 'res'. The properties below are in 'res.d'. How can I trim this object and then JSON.parse it as such:

```
res.d = JSON.parse(res.d)
```

Thanks

```
[{"id":"FARM, LODGE","name":"104"}, 
{"id":"Barn                                            
","name":"124069"},{"id":"Lg\u0027s Barn Fm                                           
","name":"124820"},{"id":"Ld\u0027s Hill Fm                 
","name":"125103"},{"id                             
":"Lord\u0027s Wood Fm                                              
","name":"125126"},{"id":"Lo\u0027s Court Fm                                           
","name":"125345"},{"id":"Lo\u0027s Copse         ","name":"162"}, 
{"id"                                       
:"Lodge              "}]
```

Comment: By trim do you mean you want to trim each value?

Comment: what's the final object you are looking. What exactly do you mean by trim the object?

Comment: By trim I mean get rid of the white space at the end and beginning of the strings in the object. Not sure what you mean by "what's the final object", the final object is the above code.

Comment: Your given object is not valid please manage and correct some wrong `"`

Comment: isn't this an array of JSON objects? I'm not sure what else to call it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const items = [
  { id: "       LODGE FARM WEST TO LOWER LODGE FARM, LOWER LODGE", name: "10444" },
  { id: "Hello world             ", name: "5555" }
];

const res = items.map(item => {
  return {
    id: item.id.trim(),
    name: item.name.trim()
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newObj = res.d.map((value) => {
      return{ 
        id: value.id.trim(),
        name: value.name.trim()
      }
    })

console.log(newObj)
```

This should trim the values in your object and 'newObj' will have new values

Answer (score 0):

You could also use lodash after requiring it in your code.
If res.d is an array of objects

```
_.map(res.d, val => _.mapValues(val, _.trim()));
```

Otherwise if res.d is an object

```
_.mapValues(res.d, _.trim);
```

Ref: https://lodash.com/docs/#trim